# Google BigQuery EXPORT DATA csv file on storage - issue special characters write badly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I need to export data of a BigQuery table into csv on Google Cloud Storage.

I used the following:

```
EXPORT DATA
    OPTIONS(
                uri=concat(path_file_output,'_*.csv'),
                format='CSV',
                overwrite=true,
                header=true,
                field_delimiter=';'
            )
AS
 SELECT * FROM my_bigquery_table
```

In my_bigquery_table there are string columns with the character '€' that are badly changed during the export
for example: a field with '1234.56 €' is changed with '1234.56 â'.

Exist a way to avoid this?
on the google documentation :https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements
there aren't any other options for the export

Comment: What's your procedure to check the file and to detect those characters? Do you use a text editor?

Comment: I checked at the end of my process the file in the google cloud storage using Excel
I saw that for the specific fields there were always a wrong character after the numbers as above 1234.56 â'  instead of '1234.56 €'.

Comment: That's my (hidden) question. Can you try to open the file with a text editor (not excel)?

Comment: hi @guillaumeblaquiere, thanks, I open the file with the text editor and the € character is here...So it is a problem of excel? 
Do I need to import the file to bypass the problem or exist another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft will be always Microsoft... Be reading the comments, the problem comes from Excel, and the default encoding format.

So, let me explain. Your system doesn't use a UTF-8 encoding format. In France, my system uses ISO8859 encoding type, and when you open a file with Excel, it doesn't understand. Same thing if you have a coma separated value (the meaning of CSV) that you import in Excel, it doesn't work in France (we have the habit to use semi-colon separated value).

Anyway. There isn't straight forward solution to open the file with Excel. But you can do it.

- Open Excel, and open a blank notebook
- Go to Data, Get Data, from text
  [image]
- Select your file and click on "get data"
- Then you can configure your import. Select UTF-8 as File Origin

[image]

And then continue with other parameters. You can see a sample of your file and the result that you will get.

*Note: I have nothing against microsoft, but when it comes to development, Microsoft is a trap nest...*